# Invalid prop: type check failed for prop "chartData". Expected Object, got Null vue.js

Tags: firebase, vue.js, chart.js, vuejs3, vue-chartjs

This is the error i am getting while running this code.
[Vue warn]: Invalid prop: type check failed for prop "chartData". Expected Object, got Null

This is how i am calling the vue-chartjs component

```js
<div class="">
   <DoughnutChart :chartData="testData" ref="doughnutRef" />
</div>
```

This is the script of the same file where i am using the chart component
Here i have initialized chartdata at the start and then i am trying to update the chart data  with the api data after doing some calculation on the data.
Like I want to view how many males and females are there.
Data is coming from firebase.

```js
<script>
import UserList from "@/components/UserList.vue";
import { defineComponent, onMounted, ref } from "vue";
import { DoughnutChart } from "vue-chart-3";
import { Chart, registerables } from "chart.js";
import { db } from "@/firebase";
import {
  collection,
  getDocs,
  deleteDoc,
  doc,
  onSnapshot,
} from "firebase/firestore";

Chart.register(...registerables);

export default {
  name: "Home",
  components: { UserList, DoughnutChart },
  setup() {
    const doughnutRef = ref([]);
    let testData = null

    onMounted(() => {
      onSnapshot(collection(db, "users"), (querySnapshot) => {
        const updateChartArray = [];
        let totalFemale = 0;
        let totalMale = 0;
        querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
          if (doc.data()["Gender"] === "M") {
            totalMale = totalMale + 1;
          } else {
            totalFemale = totalFemale + 1;
          }
        });
        updateChartArray.push(totalFemale);
        updateChartArray.push(totalMale);
        doughnutRef.value = updateChartArray;
      });

      testData = {
        labels: ["Female", "Male"],
        datasets: [
          {
            data: doughnutRef.value,
            backgroundColor: ["#77CEFF", "#0079AF"],
          },
        ],
      };
    });

    return { testData,doughnutRef };
  },
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

At the moment of component creation, `testData` is null and is immediately passed down to `DoughnutChart` component as a prop, but `DoughtnutChart` expects an object, not null, hence why you have an error.

You're not setting the value of `testData` until the `OnMounted` hook, which if you've seen the [Vue component lifecycle chart](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/lifecycle.html#lifecycle-diagram), happens some (short) time after component creation.

You either need to make sure `testData` has a value at the time of component creation, or prevent the rendering of the `DoughnutChart` component until `testData` has a value:

```html
<DoughnutChart v-if="testData" :chartData="testData" ref="doughnutRef" />
```

edit:
In addition, your `testData` variable is not reactive so it's value in the template will never actually update from being `null`.  You must assign it's initial value using `ref()`:

```js
let testData = ref(null);
```

and update anywhere you use `testData` in your `<script>` to be `testData.value` since it's now a ref, namely the OnMounted hook:

```js
onMounted(() => {
      testData.value = {
        labels: ['Female', 'Male'],
        datasets: [
          {
            data: doughnutRef.value,
            backgroundColor: ['#77CEFF', '#0079AF']
          }
        ]
      };
    });
```

Comment: sorry its not working I tried it

Comment: what does "not working" mean exactly?  are you still getting the same `Invalid prop: type check failed` error?  adding the `v-if` will 100% fix that error (or at least avoid it).  we most likely need to fix additional problems, but first you must explain the current behavior of your application because I can not offer help when the only detail I have is "its not working".

Comment: luckily I was able to find the remaining issue myself without further input.  I have updated my answer to include an additional fix: you need to assign the initial value of testData using `ref()`

Comment: here is the link to it for your refence https://notepad.pw/524y1c7x. I did the changes but its saying `TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object`

Comment: I see some of my changes... modified by you, for unknown reasons.  I also don't know where the error you posted is coming from. It would help to post the whole thing.  Actually, see my [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/distracted-paper-0wlw1p?file=/src/components/Chart.vue) for a simplified version of your component that removes the firestore functionality and JUST concentrates on getting a working DoughnutChart. Does that help at all?  When coding anything you should try getting things working one step at a time before adding more to it.  From here you can try adding back firestore

Answer (score 0):

You need to define the default value of props as null. Because initially, it's null. So the warning is showing.